# Should the keys property of cookie-session in Express.js be random?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-cookies

I have the following code:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'cookie_name',
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    keys: [v4(), v4()],
    secure: cookie_secure,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true,
    signed: true,
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
}))
```

The above code v4() is from the uuid library and will generate a random UUIDv4.

My question is pretty simple. Do I want it to be a random number, or should I manually set the keys value? I know that the secret is meant as a single key replacement for the keys value, but I can't get it to work without keys being specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it never has to be random. It only has to be "secure enough"... It's a broad statement, but anything better than "AAA" or "123" should suffice. You CAN use a random number every time, but you can also choose to manually set it.